# How to Launch a instance in VPC using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I need to launch a instance from a AMI .. moreover.. i need to launch the new instance with same attributes as the original instance from which the AMI was created.. i.e ,, same VPC id , same key_name, same _region etc etc

my code accepts is:

```
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=[sys.argv[1]])
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
for i in instances:
    key_name = i.key_name
#    security_group = "sg-f05ee295"      #i.groups
    instance_type = i.instance_type
#    print security_group[0]
#    subnet_name = i.subnet_id
    reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=ami_id,key_name=key_name,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids =['sg-f05ee295'])
    print "new replica system id is " + reserve.instances[0].id
```

This is not working, since it says::

```
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterCombination</Code><Message>VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>57c29a87-8f6c-462d-a16b-7a4888dd5341</RequestID></Response>
```

HELP ME OUT!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into same issue.. all u need to do is this

```
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=[sys.argv[1]])
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
for i in instances:
    key_name = i.key_name
    security_group = i.groups[0].id
    instance_type = i.instance_type
    print "Now Spinning New Instance"
    subnet_name = i.subnet_id
    reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=ami_id,key_name=key_name,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids=[security_group],subnet_id=subnet_name)
```

This will solve your problem. Regards \m/

Comment: yeah i checked that .. i got confused with the subnet and sec_group id stuff.. works like a charm as u said :)

Comment: Hi Nishant/Killercrock, I updated the code above , because it would not create exact replica in case there are more than 1 SG's

Comment: @padmakarojha if there's a problem with the answer, point it out in the comment and add your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

So basically , answer by Nishant will work , but you won't get exact replica just in case there are more than one SG's :

For that refer to the code below:

```
for i in instances:
    key_name = i.key_name
    security_group = []
    for each in i.groups:
         security_group.append(each.id)
    instance_type = i.instance_type
    subnet_name = i.subnet_id
    reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=ami_id,subnet_id=subnet_name ,key_name=key_name,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids =security_group)
print "new replica system id is " + reserve.instances[0].id
```

Reference : I answered the same question on this thread
[How to Launch a exact same replica of a EC2 instance in VPC from the AMI of a previous EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816924/how-to-launch-a-exact-same-replica-of-a-ec2-instance-in-vpc-from-the-ami-of-a-pr/32820695#32820695)

Comment: okay .. right .. u have also used vpc_id = i.vpc_id , is this required? because i don't see it being passed/used anywhere

Comment: Nope , its not required , subnet takes care of that part , This snippet is part of larger code , It just got left , you can ignore that Or just remove it. I will edit the same above,